# PROC PHREG - survival probability at specific point of time

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

I'm making a model in SAS using proc phreg procedure. In the output out statement it is possible to define a survival variable for each observation. This survival variable is the probability of survival until some point of time. My question is: what time is considered here? Is it a probability of surviving until time=0?

Is it possible to get a variable like this but describing a probability of surviving until some arbitraty defined point of time? (i.e. 1 year?)

My code is following:

```
ods graphics on;
proc phreg data=train outest=estimates plots=(survival cumhaz);
class &vars;
model time*censor(1)=&vars / selection=stepwise ties=efron;
output out=surv survival=s;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

Thank you in advance!